# how to use Integrate.OnClosedInterval of the library Math.Net in VB?

Tags: vb.net, math, integrate

[I read the documentation of Mathdotnet but is unintelligible](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Integrate.htm).
I don't understand how to use it at all. I would like to integrate the density function of a gamma distribution to get a conditionnal expectation.

[I found this exemple in C# but it does not work in VB.](http://www.ahuwanya.net/blog/post/introducing-csharp-pad)
To compare with the exemple above, I would like to do something like this:

`MathNet.Numerics.Integrate.OnClosedInterval(x >= Gamma.PDF(alpha, beta, x), 0, p / 100)`

What would be the equivalent in VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting your question correct then I will suggest there should be lambda expression symbol (`=>`) in your code (I tried to edit it but it was rejected)

1. It's required to Import `MathNet.Numerics` and `MathNet.Numerics.Distributions` Namespaces. For that you have to download it.
2. There's Lambda expression as First parameter of `OnClosedInterval()` so you have to do like `Function(a)` in vb.net

your vb.net code can be like this,

```
Imports System
Imports MathNet.Numerics
Imports MathNet.Numerics.Distributions

Public Module Module1
  Public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(Integrate.OnClosedInterval(Function(a) Gamma.PDF(alpha, beta, a), 0, p/100))
  End Sub
End Module
```

You can see example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZzHjP8)

Comment: I imported everything. What I was missing was: ``Function(a)`` .Thx